# React hook function call render map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase, react-hooks

Is it possible to assign the hook return function to a render map in React? The following example includes the `socialAuthMethodsMap` map with the `onClick` parameter. I want to assign the `signInWithApple` function from `useFirebaseAuth` hook, but it breaks the essential React hook laws. Is there any alternatives?

```
import {FunctionComponent, MouseEventHandler} from 'react'
import { IconProps } from 'react-feather'

type TSocialAuthMethodData = {
    code: string
    logo?: string | FunctionComponent<IconProps>
    onClick: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>
}

// const { signInWithApple } = useFirebaseAuth()

export const socialAuthMethodsMap: Array<TSocialAuthMethodData> = [
    {
        code: 'apple',
        logo: '/assets/icons/social/apple.svg',
        onClick: signInWithApple,
    },
    {
        code: 'google',
        logo: '/assets/icons/social/google.svg',
        onClick: () => null,
    },
    {
        code: 'github',
        logo: '/assets/icons/social/github.svg',
        onClick: () => null,
    },
]
```

Render function

```
<div>
            {socialAuthMethodsMap.map((socialAuthMethod) => (
                <SocialAuthButton
                    key={socialAuthMethod.code}
                    title={socialAuthMethod.code}
                    logo={socialAuthMethod.logo}
                    onClick={socialAuthMethod.onClick}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to call the hook in the component. The returned function `signInWithApple` you can do whatever you want with.

So here if you move `socialAuthMethodsMap` into the component as well as the hook then should be good.

Something like this

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const { signInWithApple } = useFirebaseAuth();

  const socialAuthMethodsMap: Array<TSocialAuthMethodData> = [
    {
      code: "apple",
      logo: "/assets/icons/social/apple.svg",
      onClick: signInWithApple,
    },
    {
      code: "google",
      logo: "/assets/icons/social/google.svg",
      onClick: () => null,
    },
    {
      code: "github",
      logo: "/assets/icons/social/github.svg",
      onClick: () => null,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      {socialAuthMethodsMap.map((socialAuthMethod) => (
        <SocialAuthButton
          key={socialAuthMethod.code}
          title={socialAuthMethod.code}
          logo={socialAuthMethod.logo}
          onClick={socialAuthMethod.onClick}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Or if you need to export it, would probably make a hook and have the array as the result.

```
export const useSocialAuthData = () => {
  const { signInWithApple } = useFirebaseAuth();

  const socialAuthMethodsMap: Array<TSocialAuthMethodData> = [
    {
      code: "apple",
      logo: "/assets/icons/social/apple.svg",
      onClick: signInWithApple,
    },
    {
      code: "google",
      logo: "/assets/icons/social/google.svg",
      onClick: () => null,
    },
    {
      code: "github",
      logo: "/assets/icons/social/github.svg",
      onClick: () => null,
    },
  ];

  return socialAuthMethodsMap;
};

const MyComponent = () => {
  const socialAuthMethodsMap = useSocialAuthData();

  return (
    <div>
      {socialAuthMethodsMap.map((socialAuthMethod) => (
        <SocialAuthButton
          key={socialAuthMethod.code}
          title={socialAuthMethod.code}
          logo={socialAuthMethod.logo}
          onClick={socialAuthMethod.onClick}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: is there a chance I can then return the same array from there? What would it look like? 

Comment: added example, should work like that, unless there's some reason you want the array outside the component, then you could make it a function and call it in the component passing it the hook result, or change the array to take the hook result field names for each item in array

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you are trying to use `signInWithApple` directly as the `onClick` event handler, however you cannot directly use hooks outside of functional components or custom hooks.

To solve this problem you can create a wrapper function `OnClickHandler` that invokes the hook and use this function as `onClick` event handler.

I hope you had imported all necessary libraries and packages, and making the given changes in code may solve your issue .

```
 import {FunctionComponent, MouseEventHandler} from 'react'
 import { IconProps } from 'react-feather'

 type TSocialAuthMethodData = {
 code: string
 logo?: string | FunctionComponent<IconProps>
 onClick: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>
 }


   //handler function to invoke the signInWithApple on onClick event
  const OnClickHandler=()=>{
  const { signInWithApple } = useFirebaseAuth();
  signInWithApple();
 }

 export const socialAuthMethodsMap: Array<TSocialAuthMethodData> = [
 {
    code: 'apple',
    logo: '/assets/icons/social/apple.svg',
    onClick: OnClickHandler,   // use the handler function 
    
 },
 {
    code: 'google',
    logo: '/assets/icons/social/google.svg',
    onClick: () => null,
 },
 {
    code: 'github',
    logo: '/assets/icons/social/github.svg',
    onClick: () => null,
 },
 ]
```

Comment: this is exactly my solution. Same issue here! :(

Comment: Okay , for this make one more change in it (I have edited the answer ), make the `o` of `onClickHandler` capital  -> `OnClickHandler`  this will make it a react component and it will resolve your issue . Please let me know is it working or not

Comment: Changing `onClickHandler` to `OnClickHandler` does nothing, the hook is still getting fired inside an event,..

Comment: `OnClickHandler` isn't a React component, it can't call React hooks.